# scanf a string with size limit without ignoring spaces

Tags: c, string, scanf

i having problem scaning strings into a matrix that each string is maximum 256 long.

it tried this but it didnt work, someone have a solution?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
    char* song[5][256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        scanf("%255[^\n]s", song[i]);
}
```

Comment: a) `char* song[5][256];` should be `char song[5][256];` b) `"%255[^\n]s"` should be `" %255[^\n]"` (added a space, removed the s).

Comment: ... and `void main()` should be `int main(void)`

Comment: and `#include<string.h>` is useless

Comment: @WeatherVane You should post that as an answer.  Unless there is a common dup for `"%[]s"`

Answer (score 1):

welcome to stackoverflow,
first of all i am not sure why you are using char *song[5][256],but you can achieve the required out by using a 2-dimentional array ie..char song[5][256].and also i am sure that using scanf function for a matrix like array will always cause a trouble.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char s[5][256];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<256;j++)
        {       char c=getchar();
            if(c=='\n'||c== EOF)

            {   
                s[i][j]='\0';
                printf("\n");
                break;
            }
            if(j<255)
                s[i][j]=c;
            if(j==255)
                s[i][j]='\0';

        }
        printf("the given string  %d is:%s \n",i+1,s[i]);

    }
    return 0;

}
```

And also i have used two for loops, for assigning the elements of that array.Now the code works fine.I used s insted of your variale name song.
Hope that I answered your question.

Comment: Great code! Only some indentation issues and you should change `char c=getchar();` into `int c = getchar(); if (c == EOF || c == '\n')`

Comment: Great! but `EOF` is an `int`, not a `char`